# What characters are allowed for the username and password in FreeRADIUS?

Tags: password, user-accounts, freeradius, charset, hostapd

I am testing the WLAN functionalities of a device connecting to a RADIUS server. This RADIUS server is located on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Stretch and is using **FreeRADIUS 3.0** and **Hostapd**. For **EAP-PEAP MSCHAPv2** the device should be able to handle usernames and passwords with special characters like:

- German umlauts
- Cyrillic letters
- Chinese characters

and so on...

Now I ask myself:

**What characters are allowed to use for the usernames and passwords defined in the authorize file of FreeRADIUS 3.0?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radius strings may be any valid UTF8 sequence.  There's no limitations on what characters can be used for a user's password or for their username.

Comment: Source: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2865#section-5.1